# receiving sms j2me

Tags: java-me, sms, wma

I am using j2me technology. I send sms and then I want to receive sms on port "0", not to go in inbox. I can receive on port "5000" but sender can not make changes, and I must receive on default port. But when I am listening on port "0" the message go to inbox. Is is possble to access the message, when my app listening od default port("0")?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for anyone finding it when searching:

Sadly you cannot receive SMS sent on the standard port with JavaME. It's just not possible with JavaME.