# Intercepting incoming text SMS in J2ME

Tags: mobile, java-me, sms

Is there any way to intercept an incoming SMS message(In J2ME), and then modify it (or fetch data from it) before going to inbox.

Suggest some methods (or code).

Comment: there might be custom API to read SMSes based on manufacturer so you can use a strategy design to have different implementations. did you try the nokia API? also is j2me the way to go?

Comment: No I'm not using Nokia API, however I want a common message intercepting application for any J2ME supported device.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with JavaME.

[receiving sms j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781332/receiving-sms-j2me)

[listening to sms, which is sent without any port number in j2me app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269017/listening-to-sms-which-is-sent-without-any-port-number-in-j2me-app)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082810/listen-for-incoming-sms-while-the-application-closed-in-blackberry

You can only receive SMS which is sent on a specific port - and standard SMS is not sent that way.